# Getting garbage value while doing chaining of assignment of class objects, using assignment operator overloading which returns class object by value

Tags: c++

In assignment operator overloading, If I return the object by reference like below

```
One& operator=( const One&  obj).
```

Then program works fine.

But if when I return by value, like below

```
One operator=( const One&  obj)
```

Then o1 gets garbage value. Can anybody explain why return by value does not work in assignment operator overloading?

```
class One
{
    public:
        One(int a1, int b1) {  
            a = a1; b = b1; 
        }

        int a;
        int b;
        One operator=( const One&  obj) { 
            cout<<"\nOperator= is called\n"; a = obj.a; b = obj.b; 
        }
};


int main()
{
    One o1(5,5);
    One o2(10,10);
    One o3(15,15);

    cout << "\no1.a=" << o1.a << ", o1.b=" << o1.b << endl;

    o1 = o2 = o3;

    cout << "\no1.a=" <<o1.a << ", o1.b=" << o1.b << endl;
    cout << "\no2.a=" <<o2.a << ", o2.b=" << o2.b << endl;
    cout << "\no3.a=" <<o3.a << ", o3.b=" << o3.b << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
o1.a=-13360, o1.b=0

o2.a=15, o2.b=15

o3.a=15, o3.b=15
```

Why o1 object showing garbage value in case of return by value in assignment operator. It works fine when return by reference. why?

Comment: You never return anything from your `operator =`.  Also the code you show does not match the signature you have in the question

Comment: Just a FYI: Since your class is a POD type there is no reason for you to write a copy assignment operator.  The compiler will provide it for you.

Answer (score 2):

`o1 = o2 = o3;` is evaluated as `o1 = (o2 = o3);`

That requires `o2 = o3` to *return* something, and `o1` is set to that value. But your overload currently doesn't. (Formally it means that the behaviour of your code is *undefined*). If you rewrite to

```
 One& operator=(const One& obj)
 {
     std::cout << "\nOperator= is called\n";
     a = obj.a;
     b = obj.b;
     return *this; // i.e. return a reference to self.
 }
```

then all will be well. That said, the cool cats will use

```
 One& operator=(One obj/*pass by value to exploit compiler optimisations*/)
 {
     std::cout << "\nOperator= is called\n";
     std::swap(*this, obj);
     return *this;
 }
```

Reference: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 1):

The code of the `=` operator should be this:

```
One & operator=(const One&  obj)
{
  cout << "\nOperator= is called\n";
  a = obj.a;
  b = obj.b;
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: That is fine, Thanks for that. Then how is it working for One&? As in case of One& Return type also, I am not returning anything.

Comment: You need to return something from an assignment operator if you want `o1 = o2 = o3;` which is actually `o1 = (o2 = o3);` to work.

Comment: @Gaurav It is called undefined behavior.  It may or may not work but it is definitely not correct.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was confused why it was working for One&. Actually it seems undefined behavior in case of not returning any value. Thanks again

Comment: @NathanOliver, Thanks mate. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 One operator=( const One&  obj)
 { cout<<"\nOperator= is called\n"; a = obj.a; b = obj.b; }
```

You do not have any return expression in your function definition, resulting in *undefined behavior*. That's why the operator does not work as it should.

In case you are using the `gcc` compiler, I would suggest you enable the `-Wall` option, which would have produced a warning, indicating the failure. In case you are using sth different there's probably an equivalent option available.

You may also want to take a look at the [Copy-and-Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) which provides an advanced insight in the creation of a properly working copy-assignment operator.